# Delete double words except some specified ones on string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to find a regex that delete double words in a string except some words i wanna specify.

This is regex i'm using

```js
    setFinal(final) {
        // remove duplicated words and eventual initial/final spaces
        let res = final.replace(/(\b\S.+\b)(?=.*\1)/g, "").trim();

        // ... other code
    }
```

If I would to specify words not to be taken into consideration, how could I do?

Comment: Do you want only the final occurrence of a word to be preserved?

Comment: Can you give an example of your input and expected output?

Comment: You are removing repeated substrings, not just words, and in any context as `\1` is not within word boundaries. You can't actually rely on this pattern to add exceptions due to the fact `.+` matches any 1+ non-linebreak chars as many as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Negative lookahead for any of those words, alternated inside a group. Note that `.` matches *any* character (except newlines), which probably isn't desirable - since you want to match *words*, probably better to use `[a-z]` or `\S` (non-whitespace characters) or something like it instead.

For example, the following removes duplicated words (leaving only the final occurrence of any particular word), *except* for occurrences of `foo` and `bar`, which are always kept.

```js
const final = 'aaa bbb foo ccc bar ddd foo bar aaa bbb';
let res = final.replace(/(\b(?!foo|bar)\S+\b)(?=.*\b\1\b)/gi, "").trim();
console.log(res);
```

Make sure to use `\b` around the backreference as well.

Comment: Note you changed the original OP pattern and it won't work now in many other cases, say with non-ASCII letters (`\S` is usually preferred to `\w` / `[a-zA-Z]` because of that).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the first occurrence of a word and remove subsequent occurrences, then it becomes far more complicated. There may be something simpler than what I came up with, but it does work:

```js
function rep()
{
    const final = 'aaa bbb foo ccc bbb bbb bbb bar ddd foo bar aaa bbb';
    let result = final;
    for (;;) {
        let m = result.match(/(\b(?!foo|bar)\S+\b)(?:.+)(\b\1\b)/i);
        if (!m) {
            return result.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim();
        }
        let s = m[1];
        let index = m.index;
        /* replace all occurences of s: */
        let regex = new RegExp("\\b" + s + "\\b", "gi");
        result = result.replace(regex, "");
        /* put pack first occurence */
        result = [result.slice(0, index), s, result.slice(index)].join('');
    }
}

console.log(rep());
```